# Select value from array keys and skip if there is no match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get all numbers after first comma in that text

```
tl.to(abstract_m, 12, {x: "271", y: "193"});
tl.set(abstract_m, {x: "0", y: "0"});
tl.to(abstract_m, 2, {x: "456", y: "424"});
```

Here code in action http://codepen.io/one2gov/pen/vyJKga?editors=1111

```
function tweenSize() {
    var selectSec = $("#fname").val().split(";");
    for (var key in selectSec) {
        var value = selectSec[key];
        if (value.split('.set') >= 0) {
            alert("you don't need this" + value.split(".set"));
        } else {
            var ShowSec = value.split(",")[1];
            alert(ShowSec);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is js doesn't let me split arrays keys properly. I am getting desired result after getting all strokes.

Result looks like:

here is stroke 1
here is stroke 2
here is stroke 3
...
you don't need stroke 2!

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: which array keys? indices?

Comment: the goal is just to add all numbers after first coma and before second coma from that text

Comment: yes indices. i thout it's keys..

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse JavaScript. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I am creating ui for one js library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting all numbers between commas, you could match commas and use a group for numbers.

```js
var text = 'tl.to(abstract_m, 12,  {x:"271", y:"193"});\ntl.set(abstract_m,  {x:"0", y:"0"});\ntl.to(abstract_m, 2,  {x:"456", y:"424"});',
    regex = /,\s(\d+),/g,
    m,
    result = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    result.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am trying to get all numbers between first and second coma. That's the problem. so it would be 12 and 2 from 1 and 3 line

Comment: Thank you very much. You made it look so easy!)